# Error as "has some invalid arguments"

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using Dataset.xsd to fill in datagrid with parameters,but it always shows error,here is the code

```
public void FillStudylist()
{
  TableAdapter.Fill(StudylistDataSet.study_list,datePicker1.SelectedDateFormat,datePicker2.SelectedDate);
  DataContext = StudylistDataSet.study_list.DefaultView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler error [*The best overloaded method match for ... has some invalid arguments*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b66k5sz9.aspx) occurs when the arguments you pass to a method do not match the method's signature in terms of type restrictions.

To solve this problem, you will need to look at the declaration of the `Fill` method you are invoking to check what arguments it expects, and then check whether the three values you pass to that method match those types.

Comment: actually am a fresher in WPF dataset,so cant get that

Comment: @user3592261: Please specify. What exactly is unclear about the error message, the [docs on the error message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b66k5sz9.aspx), or the explanation here? Note that this error is neither specific to WPF nor datasets. It is a very general error related to basic C# usage.

Comment: Now Error 'System.Windows.Controls.DatePicker' does not contain a definition for 'stdTableAdapter' and no extension method 'stdTableAdapter'

Comment: @user3592261: Well, that means that you're trying access something like `x.stdTableAdapter`, where `x` is of type `System.Windows.Controls.DatePicker`, yet [`DatePicker` does not have any member named `stdTableAdapter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.aspx).

Comment: cant get answer for my solution

Comment: @user3592261: Why, what exactly are you trying and what is happening?

Comment: i want to pass values to datepicker

Comment: @user3592261: I'm sorry, your brief descriptions of the problems you are encountering are totally insufficient for anyone else who cannot look at your screen to figure out what you have tried and what exactly you are stuck with.

Comment: i'm trying to pass value to datepicker,when am select datepicker i need to come the values to datagrid based on dataset,this is my problem